# How to prevent cached temporary files from being removed?

Tags: administration, android-sdk

I have Ubuntu14.4 on my machine, and also have downloaded Android-SDK to program for Android. When I install some package in Android-SDK, it does three things: first it downloads the package into a temp folder; second, when the download is completed, it unpacks that package into appropriate folders, and the third thing it does is to delete that package from the temp folder.
What I wish to do is to keep that package located in the temp folder, since I'm going to install another version of Ubuntu, and do not want the packages to be downloaded again. What can I do to prevent those temp packages from being removed?

Android-SDK probably uses a specific command to remove the temp packages. If I can figure out that command, and I alias the command, then the SDK wouldn't be able to remove package files anymore. I know that command "rm" is not the command of my purpose, since I've aliased it, and the SDK still was able to remove packages. How can I find the command that SDK uses?